# Why shifted value from @_ is not alias?

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, subroutine

> [**shift**](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html)
>   Shifts the first value of the array off and returns it...

This is done for speed optimization and to avoid copying by value.

Also in [**perlsub**](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

> The array @_ is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters. In particular, if an element $_[0] is updated, the corresponding argument is updated

Thus if we do `my $self =  shift` in our sub, we shift the first value from `@_`, which is an alias, is it not?

But when we compare these two:

```
sub test {
     print \$_[0];    # SCALAR(0xf73c38)
     my $x =  shift;
     print \$x;       # SCALAR(0xf79800)
}
```

We see that `$x` is the copy.

**Why is the `shift`ed value from @_ not an alias?**

So if the value is copied for the case `my $x =  shift` too, what benefit does it provide over `my $x =  $_[0]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shifted value is an alias

```
$ perl -E 'sub F{say \$_[0]; say \shift} $x=42; say \$x; F($x)'
SCALAR(0x1d7f1e0)
SCALAR(0x1d7f1e0)
SCALAR(0x1d7f1e0)
```

The assignment operation (e.g., `$x = $_[0]` or `$x = shift`) creates a copy of the scalar on the right hand side, so the newly assigned value is no longer an alias.

As toolic said, the benefit of `shift` is to modify `@_`, which sometimes makes it easier to use in the rest of your subroutine.

You could still work with a *reference* to the shifted value if you still wanted to be able to modify the input

```
$ perl -E 'sub G { my $x=\shift; $$x = 19 } my $z = 42; G($z); say $z'
19
```

Comment: And what benefit is for `$x=shift` over `$x=$_[0]`?

Comment: If I understand right the variant with `shift` will be slower, but I may gain benefit if laterly passthrough `@_` to base class

Comment: I don't know if `shift` is slow. `shift @foo` does not modify `@foo` very much, it just needs to move the pointer representing the front of the array.

Comment: The advantage of `shift` is if you're passing different sorts of things. Like for example: `my $self = shift;` when doing object oriented, and the rest of `@_` is 'arguments'.

Comment: Consider
`sub append_all { my $with=shift; map "$_$with", @_ }` versus
`sub append_all { my $with=$_[0]; map "$_$with", @_[1..$#_] }`
I think it's apparent that the first is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 3):

`shift` isn't an lvalue operator.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   sub f { shift = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
Can't modify shift in scalar assignment at -e line 3, near "456;"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

However, the values shifted from `@_` are aliases nonetheless.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   sub f { my $p = \shift; $$p = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
456
```

or

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   sub f { ${ \shift } = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
456
```

The problem is that you assigned the value of the aliased array element to `$x` rather than aliasing `$x` to array element. If you want to name the element of `@_`, you will need to alias a variable to it.

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   sub f { our $x; local *x = \shift; $x = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
456
```

or

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say );
   use Data::Alias qw( alias );
   sub f { alias my $x = shift; $x = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
456
```

or

```
$ perl -e'
   use feature qw( say refaliasing );
   no warnings qw( experimental::refaliasing );
   sub f { \my $x = \shift; $x = 456; }
   { my $x = 123; f($x); say $x; }
'
456
```

---

The benefits of `my $x =  shift` over `my $x =  $_[0];` are numerous, although minor.

- `shift` is easier to type than `$_[0]`.
- When there are more than one parameter, you can use `shift` for each rather than keeping count.
- `shift` supports complex and open-ended parameters lists. (e.g. `sub f { my $cb = shift; $cb->($_) for @_; }`)
- `shift` is microscopically faster than `$_[0]` (IIRC).